# Matplotlib figure as a new class attribute. How to show it later, on command?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using Python 3 to analyze data from experiments. For that I created a Data class with load and fit methods and what I'd like to accomplish is that both methods define (or redefine) the attribute Data.figure and after running, I'd like to be able to access that attribute and plot the figure.

So I don't know how to do to create the plot while running those methods but not get it shown during this creation but afterwards, on command, while accessing the figure attribute.

My code (not working) simplified looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def expo(x, A, inv_tau):
    return A * np.exp(-inv_tau * x)

class Data:

    def load(self, file_name, parameter, bins=50):
        """Data loading"""

        self.file_name = file_name
        self.parameter = parameter
        dt = np.dtype([(self.parameter, '<f4'), ('molecules', '<f4')])
        self.table = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=dt)

        # HISTOGRAM CONSTRUCTION
        self.mean = np.mean(self.table[self.parameter])
        self.hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(self.table[self.parameter],
                                            bins=bins,
                                            range=(0, bins * self.mean / 10))
        self.bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2
        self.bin_width = bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0]

    def plot(self):
        """Data plotting"""

        # PLOT THE HISTOGRAM
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.bar(self.bin_centres, self.hist, self.bin_width)
        self.figure = fig

    def fit(self, fit_start=0):
        """Histogram fitting"""

        self.fit_guess = [self.hist[0], 1 / self.mean]
        self.fit_par, self.fit_var = curve_fit(expo,
                                               self.bin_centres[fit_start:-1],
                                               self.hist[fit_start:-1],
                                               p0=self.fit_guess)
        self.tau = 1 / self.fit_par[1]

        # PLOT
        fig = plt.figure()
        hist_fit = expo(self.bin_centres, *self.fit_par)
        plt.bar(self.bin_centres, self.hist, self.bin_width)
        plt.plot(self.bin_centres[fit_start:-1], hist_fit[fit_start:-1])
        self.figure = fig

if __name__ == "__main__":

    data1.load(os.path.join(dirname, file_list[i]))
    data1.fit()
    print(data1.tau)

    data1.figure
```

This code has two undesired results: the fit method returns a plot figure (which I don't want) and the last line 'data1.figure' doesn't get the plot as a result, it just does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

And independently to the solving of the problem, do you think there's a better aproach to do what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `self.fig` and `self.ax` in `plot`:

```
def plot(self):
    """Data plotting"""

    # PLOT THE HISTOGRAM
    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
    hist_fit = expo(self.bin_centres, *self.fit_par)
    self.ax.bar(self.bin_centres, self.hist, self.bin_width)
    self.ax.plot(self.bin_centres[fit_start:-1], hist_fit[fit_start:-1])
```

Separate the code used to fit the data from the plotting code:

```
def fit(self, fit_start=0):
    """Histogram fitting"""

    self.fit_guess = [self.hist[0], 1 / self.mean]
    self.fit_par, self.fit_var = curve_fit(expo,
                                           self.bin_centres[fit_start:-1],
                                           self.hist[fit_start:-1],
                                           p0=self.fit_guess)
    self.tau = 1 / self.fit_par[1]
```

Then call the plot method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    data1.load(os.path.join(dirname, file_list[i]))
    data1.fit()
    print(data1.tau)
    data1.plot()
    data1.figure
```

---

If you want to reuse the same axis to do more plotting, then define the axis **once** outside of the plot method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

and pass the `ax` to the plot method as an argument:

```
def plot(self, ax):
    hist_fit = expo(self.bin_centres, *self.fit_par)
    ...    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data1.plot(ax)
```